# How do I calculate my annual percentage yield?

Tags: yield

I have an asset that I purchased at $440K.
5 years later, I sell this asset at $725K.

How do I compute the annual percentage yield that I have been getting over the past 5 years from this asset?

Comment: Were there any dividends or payments given by the asset? By yield do you mean merely your annualized rate of return?

Comment: Nope.  No dividends.  Just what I paid in for and what I got out with.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Applying some simple Math:

$725,000/$440,000 = 1.6477272727272....

So, your cumulative return is 64.8% if I round to 3 digits.

Now, if I take the 5th root of 1.648, I get approximately 1.1050742047085970060712045917364

So, your annualized rate of return is **10.5%**.

Comment: Double rounding?

Comment: @ChrisDegnen - I thought to comment on this as well. I've seen students using log tables that only have 2 significant digits and result in calculations concluding that 2^5 = 30. I tell them to round only the final result, not interim steps.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer:  especially since the unrounded intermediate result is just sitting there in your calculator, waiting to be 5th rooted.  It's actually more work to round it...

Answer (score 0):

A1 = A0 + rA0

A2 = A0 + rA0 + r(A0 + rA0) = A0 + 2rA0 + r^2A0 = A0(1 + r)^2

At = A0(1 + r)^t

r = (At/A0)^1/t - 1

r = (725/440)^1/5 - 1 = 10.5%

Comment: Is someone out there allergic to simple algebra?

Comment: Maybe if you put in some explanation it would help.